# Prestashop 1.7 total calculated incorrectly

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I'm running an online store using Prestashop. I always try to keep the software up-to-date, using the one-click update module (currently running 1.7.4.2). But one of the last updates introduced a problem: The total in the shopping cart and on checkout are not displayed correctly when using a discount code.
[image of the shopping cart with a discount code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXUNT.jpg)

As you see in the picture, the discount is calculated correctly, but the total isn't. Here's the cart-summary-totals.tpl of my theme:

```
{block name='cart_summary_totals'}
<div class="cart-summary-totals">
    <span class="label"><strong>{$cart.totals.total.label} {$cart.labels.tax_short}</strong></span>
    <span class="value"><strong>{$cart.totals.total.value}</strong></span>     
</div>
{/block}
{block name='cart_summary_tax'}
<div class="cart-summary-line">
    <span class="label sub"><small>{$cart.subtotals.tax.label}</small></span>
    <span class="value sub"><small>{$cart.subtotals.tax.value}</small></span>
</div>
{/block}
```

I really don't know what's causing this, and people in the prestashop forum ignore my post, so I hope I can get some help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone stumbles upon this problem as well, here's the solution.

Turns out that this is a bug of the Prestashop core. I submitted a bug report and it was reproduced and confirmed. In the meantime someone posted a solution on the github thread that seems to work for everyone. More over here:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/10264